# C Application crashes inside the JNI Call

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

My C Application crashes inside the JNI call in following stack after some time. Any one having any idea what is going on.

Will that be a problem in my code or inside JVM?

```
#0  0x00007fc3c16a38e5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fc3c16a50c5 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fc3c29c2a55 in os::abort(bool) () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fc3c2b42f87 in VMError::report_and_die() () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fc3c29c796f in JVM_handle_linux_signal () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  <signal handler called>
#6  0x00007fc3c27dccc0 in jni_invoke_nonstatic(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*) ()
   from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#7  0x00007fc3c27ed479 in jni_CallIntMethodV () from /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#8  0x00007fc3c3032a47 in JNIEnv_::CallIntMethod (this=0x150a1e8, obj=0x150b468, methodID=0x156aa58) at /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22/include/jni.h:955
```

Comment: Your process gets an unexpected [signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and terminates. Judging by the name `report_and_die`, that function should give you some kind of report about what happened.

Comment: `Will that be a problem in my code or inside JVM?` 9 times out of 10 (or maybe 99 out of 100) answer is `your code`.. personal experience :(

Comment: Show us some code - how Java method looks and how exactly you call it.